# Solr facet Filtering

Tags: solr, facet, faceted-search

I have these fields in Solr

```
"IsFair": "True",
"IsHeight" : "True",
"IsFat" : "false",
"IsManly" : "False"
```

But while filtering data I want them to display as Fair, Height, Fat, Manly in a single field at the front end.

[image]

Something like FilterName "Appearance Type" and in that, I should have "Fair", "Height", "Fat", "Manly" as filters. Someone suggested me to use Hybrid Filter but I didn't understand how to achieve this.

Comment: Any reason why you can't index them to a separate field as well? It'll be far easier to handle and to extend in the future.

Comment: Are these different values for the same category (Appearance type)? Or different categories with each of them having separate values?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way of implementation will be to create a multivalued field **appearance_type** of type **String** and generate facet on the field **appearance_type**, later while applying the filter you can use the same field.

So your example document will have,

```
{
  "id":"doc1",
  "appearance_type":["fair","height"]
}
```